# Iphone device getting the user location define in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using CLLocationManger to get device current location. All is going well on simulation. I check the "Allow Location Simulation" and set Sydney, Australia as default location. I got the lat and long of Sydney on simulator that is fine

My problem is that when i try on device I still get the Sydney location however my device current location is India.

My device get the location what ever I set in Xcode.

Here is my code:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = 1;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];



#pragma mark delegate method which tell the current location

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    latitudeCurrentLocation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    longitudeCurrentLocation= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    locationManager=nil;
    NSLog(@"OldLocation %f %f", oldLocation.coordinate.latitude, oldLocation.coordinate.longitude);
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

}
```

Please suggest what should I should do.

Comment: Show the delegate code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this delegate method and check your location address

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

Here is sample code :

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{


    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:_locationManager.location
                   completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                       NSLog(@"reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler: Completion Handler called!");

                       if (error){
                           NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
                           return;

                       }

                       NSLog(@"placemarks=%@",placemarks);
                       CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

                       NSLog(@"placemark.ISOcountryCode =%@",placemark.ISOcountryCode);
                       NSLog(@"placemark.country =%@",placemark.country);

                       NSLog(@"placemark.postalCode =%@",placemark.postalCode);
                       NSLog(@"placemark.administrativeArea =%@",placemark.administrativeArea);
                       NSLog(@"placemark.locality =%@",placemark.locality);
                       NSLog(@"placemark.subLocality =%@",placemark.subLocality);
                       NSLog(@"placemark.subThoroughfare =%@",placemark.subThoroughfare);






                       NSLog(@"stringlocation:%@",_cityString);
                   }];
    _userLocation = [locations lastObject]; // This will give you co-ordinates

    [_locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];



}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run this in your device select don't simulate location

Comment: You mean from within Xcode? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/articles/simulating_locations.html

Comment: @bhaskae i do not have don't simulate location whoever there is none. if i select none then it goes to failure delegate method

Comment: What is the failure error? Have you denied location services to your app in privacy settings?  By the way, the delegate method you are using is deprecated.  It is replaced by `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`

Comment: No. i did not denied. now i using locationmanager:didupdateLocations